# Ubuntu is sluggish and feels slow

Tags: 14.04, drivers, intel-graphics, mesa

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my Lenovo s20-30. This is fresh install. System is quite slow, I thought it may be driver problem. How to check if I'm not missing some drivers or I need to configure?

```
cichociemny@cichociemny-Lenovo-S20-30:~$ lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation ValleyView Gen7 (rev 0e)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3807
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: done, sorry for bad formatting

Comment: Looks OK. What are the specs of this laptop?

Comment: http://www.notebookcheck.net/Lenovo-S20-30-Netbook-Review.130285.0.html Not the best,maybe i should install other distro

Comment: Maybe it is better to install Lubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem, lenovo s20-30 laptop that hangs frequently on 'Linux' would probably the best title for this thread.

I'm using Xubuntu 15.10
With this lspci -k Output:

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display (rev 0e)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3807
    Kernel driver in use: i915

I think moving on to other Distro is not the solution? This laptop works fine under Windows 10; I think the current driver on Ubuntu doesn't work well with the hardware. And that might be the real issue here, not the Distro.

Answer (score 0):

Lubuntu or Xubuntu solves many issues.  Not fancy but does best what operating systems are supposed to do.  Runs your programs when you want them without waiting.  xubuntu is easier.